# Question about a Harmonic function (Natural log of the absolute value of a harmonic function)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic in domain $D$ and cannot be $0$ for any $z$ in $D$, show that $\psi =\log_e(|f(z)|)$ is harmonic in $D$.

I believe this involves the use of $f$'s Laplacian $\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$ and the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, 
   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: I have subbed $f$ into $\psi$ and obtained $\log_e(\sqrt(u^2 +y^2))$. Not sure if this is the correct way, since the imaginary part has been completely annihilated, leaving only a new "$u$", which I define $h$.